# Windows User home directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

So odd situation here. in AD, we have our user's home directory set as a network drive (D:), so when you open command prompt, it starts you in D:. I need to make a script that copies a file to their desktop. I can't use %userprofile% because it will use D:. Any ideas?

Comment: create a new path profile %userprofiled%  and use that new user profile in your script.

Comment: You could begin by editing your question to provide the content from the following command, entered at the Command Prompt: `For %G In (Home User)Do @Set %G`

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` is the profile directory (i.e. the location of the user's ntuser.dat profile). This is not necessarily the same as the home directory `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. By default, a user's known folders such as the user's "Desktop" are located in the profile directory, not the home directory. However, almost all of a user's known folders can be redirected elsewhere, such as the UNC path of their home directory. Batch scripting provides no way to 100% reliably determine the current location of known folders. You can query the value in the registry, but that may be stale data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, I was able to use `C:\users\%username%\desktop` or `%UserProfile%\Desktop`.

Comment: So you're not going to do what I asked in my comment then! Please understand that this is a two way process, you asked a poor question with insufficient supporting information for us to assist you. I asked you to provide more information, and over five hours later you posted a poor answer, ignoring that request.